# Exclude Magento admin directory from .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, magento, magento-1.7

On our Magento site we have added this to .htaccess to clean up the URLs and avoid 'duplicate' pages:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ http://oursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, for some reason we lose functionality in the backend when `oursite.com/index.php/admin/` redirects to `oursite.com/admin/`.

I have looked and can't seem to find the correct way of fixing this, all the solutions I've found seem to be about excluding a top level directory.

Comment: For starters change the name admin to something less obvious. Not having you admin panel in /admin location is the basics of security.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but we have changed it in the past and it caused issues. We did some research and decided it wasn't so important.

Comment: Did you enable 'Use Web Server Rewrites' in admin

Comment: Did you change the admin url in the admin? You need to do it in /app/etc/local.xml

Comment: Should not cause any issue if done properly, and I am not sure where you did this research but trust me any starting hacker when he wants to attack you website he goes to yourwebsite.com/admin

Comment: I strongly recommend that you take a look of the sample .htaccess that come with magento, else you may run into alot more issues.

Comment: Web Server Rewrites is enabled, but using the method from http://www.bestdesigns.co.in/blog/remove-index-php-url-magento didn't work, as urls with /index.php/ in them didn't redirect

Answer (score 0):

It was really simple in the end, I just added

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(admin|user)($|/) - [L]
```